# Android Repeating alarm manager in every 30sec

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to fire android alarm manager in every 30 sec(even my application in deep sleep  mood in background) since i need to collect GPS location in every 30sec and upload to server.

```
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(this, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);              
mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 30000,
                30000,
                pi);
```

I have use above code and it is working fine when device is in not sleep mood.But seems like it is not working properly in sleep mood.
After some times it is fires in 5 min intervals.

My application is running on android 5.0.2 Samsung Tablet.

I have found there is an issue related to Alarm manager in android 5.0 above (Specially samsung devices)
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82001

any workaround for this ?

Thanks.

Comment: if this is caused of a power save mode, the only way is to whitelist your app manually and inform your users by dialog about this. I had a similar problem on Huawei Mate 7 (lollipop & Marshmallow), they also had implemented their own power management and there is no way to get rid of this.

Comment: And a warning: In future versions, or better since Marshmallow, you can´t use this method (setRepeating). And AlarmManager is limited to fire only every 9 minutes, so it will be a hard task and you have to do some workarounds. See Doze Mode Docs:  https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

Comment: Ok thanks. if there is any other way to get GPS location in background ? my application need to capture GPS location more than one day.  i think service is not a reliable solution for this and most examples are using alarm manager/wake lock to achieve this.

Comment: not on that doze mode stuff. The only way is to whitelist and use setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(). You have to get sure your app is not going into standby, so I think a combination of wakeup, alarmManager and maybe a foregroundservice could work. But you have to test this. Doze mode is good for users, but what´s missing here is, that the user itself should decide about it, but that is not possible.

Comment: I am currently testing by myself how I can get rid of this because I am developing a chat application and a chat app shouldn´t go into standby.

Comment: for chat application .if you are using GCM(push notification) ..it will work without any issue..but if you are using socket connection using android service, i think same issue can be happen when doze mode.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but GCM is not an option because I am using smack and xmpp. Some features that are available at xmpp are not available via GCM. And I´m  really against this restriction, the limitation of ggogle to guarantee only GCM to work is an apple-like way. Anyway, If I find a solution, I hope I can remeber this discussion to give you some point to start.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Looking forward to your insight.

Comment: it´s just a consideration: What about if you implement the alarmManager to simply wake up the device. Between, implement a service with a handler or a countdowntimer that collects the data every 30 seconds. Maybe a foreground service if neccessary....that could work....

Answer (score 0):

Use setInexactRepeating for above 5.0 and use RTC_WAKEUP. This will trigger the alarm for sure even if mobile is in sleep mode. This worked for me.
IF you dont want to use Service for getting GPS locations. You can put the Maps related code inside the Broadcast Receiver and code for uploading to the server. In worst case Service is the best option for background process like capturing the GPS location.

Comment: I tried this on Huawei version 5.1.1 tablet and it is not working.